# const correctness problem with copy constructor?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, gsl

I am trying to wrap a C structure in a C++ class to take advantage of memory management and such. I have mad the structure a private member and provided a public function to provide access. The return type is constant, since all functions that take the object as an argument have `const` in their signature.

```
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

class GSLRand {
    gsl_rng* r_;    // see links below

public:
    GSLRand() {
        gsl_rng_env_setup();
        r_ = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_default);
    }

    ~GSLRand() {
        gsl_rng_free(r_);
    }

    const gsl_rng* rng() {
        return r_;
    }   
};
```

That all compiles nicely. The problem occurs when I get clever and try to add a copy constructor. Introducing it into the class like...

```
public:
....
    GSLRand(const GSLRand& R) {
        r_ = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_taus);
        gsl_rng_memcpy(r_, R.rng());
}
....
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
GSLRand.h: In copy constructor ‘GSLRand::GSLRand(const GSLRand&)’:
GSLRand.h:35: error: passing ‘const GSLRand’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘gsl_rng* GSLRand::rng()’ discards qualifiers
```

I'm using g++ on a Mac. I have tried the different variants and still can't figure out how I'm confusing the compiler (or myself!). Interestingly, I get the identical error when I remove the `const` specifier from `rng()`.

Any ideas?

For documentation of the functions that are used:
[random number generation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Generation.html), the sections on "environment variables" and "copying generators."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `rng()` const function: `const gsl_rng* rng() const {`.

Comment: wilx is right. const gsl_rng* rng(){} only says that the returned pointer is const but you have to state that the function doesn't modify the object, too. This is the second const before the {}

Comment: There's more to it than this.

Answer (score 3):

Change this function to:

```
const gsl_rng* rng() const {
    return r_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.  First, you are calling a non-`const` member function through a `const` object reference.  Can't do that.  You can make `GSLRand::rnd()` a `const` member function:

`const gsl_rng* rng() const {`

...but then you have a second problem: `gsl_rng()` returns a `const gsl_rng*`, but you're trying to assign this to a non-`const` member variable.  Can't do that, either.

Fork in the road.  Either you always call `const` member functions on through the `r_` pointer, or you sometimes call non-`const` member functions through it.

If you always call `const` member functions, then make the member variable point to a `const gsl_rng`:

```
const class gsl_rng* r_;    // see links below
```

Otherwise, make your `rng()` function return a non-`const` pointer, while keeping the method itself `const`:

```
gsl_rng* rng() const {
        return r_;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've always wondered what those <code>const</code> between the declaration and definition means. This is really helpful.

Comment: @Jerry:  You're welcome.  Just by way of brief explanation, when you declare a member function `const`, you are telling the compiler to interpret the `this` pointer as `const`, so you won't be able to call any non-`const` member functions or change any non-`mutable` member variables.